# How to i redirect the root path to devise's login page?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I know this shouldn't be done.. but i need the home page to be the login page

My sessions new is inside

View> Users > Sessions > New

Help? How do i root it i've tried root :to => "Users/sessions#new" without succsess

```
uninitialized constant Users
```

Comment: what's the sessions controller do you have, users_sessions_controller?

Comment: You can also run ```rake routes``` to make sure your users controller is being recognized (should see routes related to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of complicated routes, you could just do this in controller. In whichever controller's action normally handles rendering of the Home page, redirect to the new user session page if there is no user logged in.

If you have no explicitly defined action because you're relying on Rails defaults, just write a new, very simple action that redirects if there's nobody logged in, else drops through and lets Rails take care of rendering.

Comment: but that gives an ugly url in the browser.

Comment: You'd be redirecting to a URL based on a dedicated controller with a name, and thus (at least by default) a routed URL, which explicitly describes the action being performed. I can't think of a *less* ugly URL...